# Solve the particular solution of the IVP $y' + 5xy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My background in differential equation is beginner, as I've just started this chapter in my book. The question asks for me to determine from y the particular solution of the IVP.

$y' + 5xy = 0$

I know that $y = ce^{-2.5x^2}$ (as provided by the book), although I'm misunderstanding the procedure for this (the book does not actually explain it but it just gives examples).

I had assumed, $y = e^{\int5xdx} \implies y = e^{2.5x^2}+C$

Then this is somehow transitioned into $ce^{-2.5x^2}$. However, what confuses me further is that the book mentions at $y(0) = \pi$, how does it get this?

This is from the first chapter by Keyszig for Advanced engineering mathematics.

I think it's approached this way after the comments:

$y = ce^{-2.5x^2}$, $y' = -5xce^{-2.5x^2}$

This means that:
$$y' +5xy = (-5xce^{-2.5x^2} + 5xce^{-2.5x^2})=0$$ which verifies that it's a solution.

Then $y(0) = ce^{-2.5(0)^2} \implies y(0) = c$ because $y(0 = \pi$ then $c = \pi$

Comment: $y'+5xy=0$ is not an IVP! What does the book say an "IVP" is, exactly?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich An Initial Value Problem, though it does say to 'Verify that y is a solution of the ODE'.

Comment: You need to know some algebra. $e^{\int 5x}=e^{2.5x^2+c}=e^{2.5x^2}e^c$, **not**  $e^{2.5x^2}+e^c$.

Comment: Right, an IVP is an Initial Value Problem. Now what does the book say an "initial value problem" is?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for showing me this! It mentions that the IVP is an ODE together with an initial condition. Hence a particular solution, is obtained from a general solution by an initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich you are right, I made a slight mistake with the wording but I have updated it. What does this actually mean, is the initial condition the exponential?

Comment: the initial condition is the "condition" $y(0)=\pi$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks! I'm still getting used to the terminology and logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODE is with separable variables:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-5xy\rightarrow \frac{dy}{y}=-5xdx$$
$$\ln{y}=-\frac{5}{2}x^2+C\rightarrow y=\exp{\left(-\frac{5}{2}x^2+C\right)}=e^Ce^{\left(-\frac{5}{2}x^2\right)}$$
The integration constant $C$ can be found by the initial condition $y(0)=\pi$ which is defined in the problem.

So $f(0)=e^C=\pi\implies C=\ln\pi,$ hence

$$y=f(x)=\pi e^{\left(-\frac{5}{2}x^2\right)}$$